# Write own Angular2 Annotation

Tags: dom, annotations, angular, components

Today, I trying to make my own annotation to use it in Angular2 project.
This annotation must add body class on specific component.

So, I've search on Angular source code, but it's so difficult to see where and how annotation was created.

For the moment, I've tried this :

```
export function BodyClass(classes: any): ClassDecorator{
    classes = classes || {};

    if(typeof classes === 'string'){
        classes = {classes};
    }

    return function changeBodyClass(){
        console.log('ici');
    }
}
```

And my component :

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {RouterOutlet} from "angular2/router";
import {BodyClass} from "../core/annotations/body_class";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
})
@BodyClass('test')
export class MyComponent{
}
```

My console log in the annotation was correctly fired, but I want to use "DOM" class from `angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter` to add my classes, but DOM in undefined when on console log it (not need to instanciate it).

However, the DOM class works well directly in my component.
I add classes in ngOnInit function, and remove them on ngOnDestroy.

But, I want this behavior on many component, and I think a new annotation is the best way.

Maybe you have a better idea for this ? Or to work with DOM class on a annotation ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It's not so obvious since you want to work at the component instance level and not at the component class one. So you need to wrap the corresponding constructor function.

```
export function MyComponentDecorator(value: string) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    var original = target;

    function construct(constructor, args) {
      var c : any = function () {
        // Call the target constructor
        var ret = constructor.apply(this, args);

        // Add your additional processing

        return ret;
      }
      c.prototype = constructor.prototype;
      return new c();
    }

    // The new constructor
    // Don't forget to add a name at this function
    // since Angular requires it for the template compilation
    var f : any = function WrappedComponent(...args) {
      return construct(original, args);
    }

    f.prototype = original.prototype;

    return f;
  }
}
```

At this point, you wrap the component instance but you lose the component metadata. You need to copy them by hand:

```
f.prototype = original.prototype;

var annotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', original));
Reflect.defineMetadata('annotations', annotations, f);

var properties = Reflect.getMetadata('propMetadata', original));
Reflect.defineMetadata('propMetadata', properties, f);

return f;
```

To use this decorator simply add it before or after the `@Component` one:

```
@MyComponentDecorator()
@Component({
  selector: 'sub', 
  template: `
    <div (click)="showMessage()">Test</div>
  `
})
export class SubComponent {
  (...)
}
```

You can notice that this decorator only copies the metadata at the component level and not the other ones like properties (with `@Input`)...

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/PrAvliIpWTNFAtH33bHA?p=preview.

Comment: Hmm thanks Thierry. I will check your plunkr with your explanation, and I will be back ;)